# How to solve "We found conflicting component dependencies." for paypal update?

Tags: magento-2.3

When updating the **paypal/module-braintree** extension on Magento V2.3 Community edition from version **3.0.6** to **3.1.0**, I'm getting the following error: We found conflicting component dependencies. What should i change in my composer file to fix this error?

The same error is appearing when I try to install an order tracking extension https://marketplace.magento.com/evincemage-module-trackorder.html

I'm using Ultimo Theme:
https://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798

[image]

My composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "aramex/shipping": "1.0.0",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.0",
        "paypal/module-braintree": "3.0.6",
        "stripeofficial/module-core": "2.0.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.3.9",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.3.0",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

remove this from your composer.json file

```
},
"require-dev": {
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.3.9",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1"
```

Comment: thank you for replying to my question. But it's been 6 months i asked this question and i didn't get a reply so i had to switch some extension in order for other to work. I can't give you a clear result now until i try it again once it happens.